# Import data from one workbook and paste to last line of table of another workbook?

Tags: excel, vba

I’m a total newbie with this and have been using guides I’ve found online. However I am not having much luck.

I am trying to import data from specific columns into a table (columns A, B, E and F to be precise, starting from row 2). I will be importing data from multiple files over time so wanted the ability to open the file and add the data to last line of the table.

This is what I’m using so far, I know it’s totally incorrect however when running the VBA the table remains blank.

```
Sub Get_Data_From__Incident_File()

    Dim INCcopy As Worksheet
    Dim INCdest As Worksheet
    Dim destINC As Workbook
    Dim FileToOpen As Variant
    Dim cRow As Long
    
    Set destINC = ThisWorkbook
    Set INCdest = destINC.Sheets(1)

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    FileToOpen = Application.GetOpenFilename(Title:="Browse for Incident File", FileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xls*), *xls*")
    
    If FileToOpen <> False Then Exit Sub
        
    Set OpenBook = Application.Workbooks.Open(FileToOpen)
    With Sheets(1)
        cRow = .Cells(Row.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .Range("A2:0" & cRow).Copy
        INCdest.Cells(INCdest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
    
    End With
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    Application.CutCopeMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Any ideas how I can fix this? Thanks

I have tried to use this to no avail. Was expecting it to at least paste a value on to table but it didn’t.

Comment: `Range("A2:0" & cRow).Copy` needs a letter not a number 0 (zero). only FYI